# Why is the maximum potential energy greater than the maximum kinetic energy?

Tags: boundary-conditions, differential-equations, plotting, conservation

I was plotting the energy variation in a mass-spring system. If I define the initial conditions to be at maximum displacement from the origin, the potential energy is plotted correctly but kinetic energy isn't. However, if I define the initial conditions to be at the zero position and maximum velocity, kinetic energy is plotted correctly but the potential energy isn't. Where is the problem exactly?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate

# Potential energy V and kinetic energy KE
V = []
KE = []
 
# Defining the differential equation regarding springs 
def spring(x, t, b, w, p):
  return np.array([x[1], -b*x[1] - w*w*(x[0])**(p-1)])

# Defining some parameters
b = 0.0 
w = math.pi/2  
p = 2 

# initial condition and timeframe 
x_init = np.array([0.0, 1.0]) # Initial displacement and initial velocity respectively
t = np.linspace(0, 50, 10000)  

# Solving the differential equation
solution = integrate.odeint(spring, x_init, t, args=(b, w, p))

# Calculating the KE and V for the system
for i in solution[:, 0]:
  k = 10
  V.append((1/2) * k * i**2)

for i in solution[:, 1]:
  m = 1
  KE.append(1/2 * m * i**2)  

# Defining mechanical energy ME to be the sum of both energies.
ME = np.add(V, KE)

# Plotting the results
plt.plot(t, V, color = 'red')
plt.plot(t, KE, color = 'green')
plt.plot(t, ME, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined your potential energy incorrectly.

Your spring forcing function is
$$
F = b x + w^2 x^{p-1}
$$
The change in potential energy is defined as
$$
\Delta V = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F dx = \left.\frac{1}{2} b x^2 + \frac{w^2}{p} x^p \right|_{x_0}^{x_1}
$$
Substituting in $x_0 = 0$ and your constants for $b$, $w$, and $p$ gives
$$
V(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{8} x^2
$$
Using this definition of potential energy you get the correct plots where total energy is always constant:
[image]

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I was working on forces and forgot that I defined the potential energy differently :) Thanks a lot.